# vba replacing two quotation marks with one / generating txt files

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, string-concatenation

I have created a macro that generates txt files with data from every row in excel. I have problem with " (quotation marks)

Here is a line from VBA that makes problems:

```
wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value = "The ""Number"" is " & wsSource.Cells(r, 3).Value
```

I need this: `The "Number" is MYNUMBER`

Instead of i get this: `" The ""Number"" is" MYNUMBER`

This does not work either:

`wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value = "The" & Chr(34) & "Number"" is " & Chr(34) & wsSource.Cells(r, 3).Val` (got the same output)

I tried replacing `""` with `Chr(34)` (didn't worked)

I also tried replace function at the end:

`wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value = Replace(wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value, """", """)` (didn't worked) and
`wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value = Replace(wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value, """", Chr(34))` (didn't worked as well)

Replace() does works with other `Chr()` or with `Replace(wsTemp.Cells(6, 1).Value, """", "")` but not with Chr(34)

Anyway, i need one ", not two ' or anything else

I am saving generated files as xlCurrentPlatformText and .txt, I have also tried other formats

Also, I have noticed this when I manually saved the same text from excel as txt

I have tried almost everything and nothing worked

I am using Win 7 and Excel 2013

Comment: I think the problem is with how Excel saves to text files, not with the formulas you're using. See [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/867101/excel-adds-double-quotes-on-csv-export). You may need to use VBA to write the text file the way you want, or do some other hack (e.g., use $$$ as placeholders for quotes, then do a search/replace on the text file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did it as @xidgel suddgested, with FindAndReplaceText (fart)

I replaced all `"` with `$$$$`

I created a file replace.bat

```
fart -r "MYLOCATION*.txt" $$$$ \"
```

And added shell execute command at the end of vba macro

```
Call Shell("C:\LOCATION\replace.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as one of these,

```
With wsTemp.Cells(6, 1)
    .Value = Format(wsSource.Cells(r, 3).Value2, "\T\h\e \""\N\u\m\b\e\r\"" \i\s 0")
    .Offset(1, 0) = "The ""Number"" is " & wsSource.Cells(r, 3).Value2
    .Offset(2, 0) = "The " & Chr(34) & "Number" & Chr(34) & " is " & wsSource.Cells(r, 3).Value2
End With
```